# React Response Cookies Not Set On browser Cookies store on cross-site (Vercel app and render server)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I deployed an app on vercel which use jwt for user authentication after login and also deployed a server on render which receives request from vercel react app but after logging in, cookies are sent via the request which is visible in the response headers but not set in the browser cookies store. I set withCredentials to true and also credentials to include. and the same applies to server side but nothing happens.
I have tried all possible solutions but none solved this issue.

Here is the code from the server:

```
const auth = await bcrypt.compare(pwd, user.pwd);
    if (auth) {
        const token = createToken(user.user_id);
        res.cookie('author_JWT', token, {
            maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'none',
            path: '/'
        });

        res.status(200).send({
            user: user.user_id
        });
```

Here is the code from the app:

```
 fetch(`${url}/system/login`, {
        method: `POST`,
        credentials: `include`,
        withCredentials: true,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            uname,pwd
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
    .then((data) => {
        resolve(data.json())
        console.log(data)

    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
    })
```

Comment: Hi I have the same error, did you fine the solution ?